# How to persist scopes across requests with Rails and HasScope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, query-string, actionview, named-scope

I have a simple search and filter page.

**Class Product (Model):**

```
scope :country, ->(country){ where(:country => country) }
scope :search, ->(search) { where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{search}%")) }
```

**Class ProductController (Controller):**

```
has_scope :country
has_scope :search

def index
  @products = apply_scopes(Product)
end
```

Scopes are working as expected (e.g.)

> products?search=computer
>
> products?search=computer&country=australia
>
> products?country=australia

**Problem scenario:**
When I want to filter the results by country after a search I am unable to establish the correct query string.

**Search View:**

```
=form_tag products_path, :method => 'get' do
  =text_field_tag :search, '', placeholder: "Enter name of product"
  %button{:type => "submit"}
```

**Produces:**

> /products?search=xxx

Which is okay.

**Filter View:**

```
=form_for :country,  :method => :get  do |f|
  =f.collection_select :country, @countries, :id, :country
  =f.submit "Search"
```

**Produces:**

> /products?country=xxx

This overwrites the entire URL. How can I get such a URL when filtering.

> /products?**search=xxx**&country=xxx

How can I keep the search query string when I want to filter  results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hidden field to your filter form, which will re-submit the current search along with the filter:

```
= form_for :country,  :method => :get  do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :search, value: params[:search]
  = f.collection_select :country, @countries, :id, :country
  = f.submit "Search"
```